# Use dataframe column names as labels in pylab.plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, label

I would like to plot the data in a dataframe and have the column headers be the labels.  I tried this:

```
dfm.columns = ['a','b']
plot(dfm.cumsum(), label= dfm.columns.values)
legend(loc='upper left')
```

But got this:

[image]

Instead of both lines being labeled ['a','b'], I'd like the blue line to be a and the green to be b using `pylab`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's the way you have your data set up in part of the code you're not showing.

Here's an example, I used `df.plot()` in this case.

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [random.randint(10,20) for r in range(100)]
y = [random.randint(0,10) for r in range(100)]

df = pd.DataFrame([x,y]).T #T for transpose

df.columns=['a','b']

df.plot(kind='line')

plt.legend(loc='upper left')

plt.show()
```

[image]

**Edit**

`pylab` version

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

x = [random.randint(10,20) for r in range(100)]
y = [random.randint(0,10) for r in range(100)]

df = pd.DataFrame([x,y]).T

plt.plot(df)

plt.legend(['a','b'],loc='upper left')

plt.show()
```

Comment: df.plot() correctly shows the labels, as you say.    plot(df) was what I was doing, and does not.   It seems like the 'label=' part of the plot(...) call ought to take a list or series or something and apply the values according, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: The question was partially about setting labels in pylab.plot, and I still don't know how to do that.  If some one else is trying to do the same thing, and I accept this answer, I don't think that would be right.  Are you saying that the answer is "you can't do that with pylab.plot, you have to use df.plot?

Comment: @lem  Better is plt.legend(df.columns.values,loc='upper left').   That's what I was missing.  Thanks.